# Get name and depth of new enumitem list

Tags: environments, lists, enumitem

I have an itemize environment defined by `newlist`:

```latex
\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[questions,1]{label=\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*}
...
```

I'd like to know at an arbitrary point inside one of these environments what the name of the environment is and what the current depth is (or some equivalent)

I found out that the macro `\@listctr` seems to be the name of the current list counter with the information I need (e.g. `questionsii`) but I can't seem to compare it with the list name (e.g. `\ifthenelse{\equal{\@listctr}{questionsii}}`, `\ifx\@listctr\questionsiiname` with appropriate `questionsiiname`, etc).

With a plain enum, I could use `\@enumdepth`, but I can't find anything similar for `enumitem`'s custom lists. I also ideally would not like to check the current environment so I can call this within an environment within a list.

What might I do to get or save+get this information?

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[questions]{label*=\arabic*.}

\makeatletter
\def\currentlist{???} % ???=/@listctr, /@enumctr, etc.
\makeatother

\def\questionsiiname{questionsii}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \item Hello world. The current list is ``\currentlist''.
    \begin{questions}
        \item My depth is: \ifx\currentlist\questionsiiname 2! \else ??? \fi.
    \end{questions}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please can you add a minimal working example? Thank you.

Comment: @Sebastiano I've updated the question. The MWE shows trying to get the current list name, but I would be just as happy with another way to get the current list and depth such as a list name and depth counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the current list can be found with `\@currenvir`. The depth of an `enumitem` custom list is stored in the macro `\enitdp@listname`.  So we can construct a macro to print the list name and current depth:

```
\makeatletter
\def\currentlist{\@currenvir~\the\csname enitdp@\@currenvir\endcsname}
\makeatother
```

Since I'm not quite sure what you want to do with the information I won't try to expand on your example's conditional.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[questions]{label*=\arabic*.}

\makeatletter
\def\currentlist{\@currenvir~\the\csname enitdp@\@currenvir\endcsname}%
\makeatother

\def\questionsiiname{questionsii}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \item Hello world. The current list is ``\currentlist’’.
    \begin{questions}
        \item The current list is  ``\currentlist’’
    \end{questions}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you! This works well. I am wondering if there is a way to get the enumerate name even when within a different environment.

Comment: @thshea I'm not sure what you mean. The name is just whatever you name it no?  If you want to manipulate the depth counter you don't need to use `\@currenvir` you can use (in your example) `\enitdp@questions`.